# Matplotlib: plotting distorted axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bunch of values that I wanna plot:

```
{'A': 0.9823, 'B': 0.9133, 'C': 0.9987, 'D': 0.7332, 'E': 0.1345, 'F': 0.9235}
```

A straightforward bar chart of these, along the range of y values [0, 1], would see some very tall bars, and a couple of shorter ones (D and E).  I'd like to accentuate the display of variability in heights by, instead of having y tickmarks:

```
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3...0.8, 0.9, 1]
```

we have:

```
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 1]
```

I've searched the docs, but there seems to be no easy way to do this.

Note that these are actually percentages, so fold changes or converting into a log scale won't work so well.

Comment: How do you plan to map e.g. your first value 0.9823 to an ordinate value between 0.9 and 0.99?  Linearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is a transformation for your data so that values closer to one are more spaced apart. There are a few different options for functions that will do this, one I have used in the past is:

[image: formula]

Where the value of [image: formula] will determine the amount of  "stretching" near values of 1. Here is some code demonstrating the effect this has.

There are plenty of other transformations (functions) you can use.

Also note that I used the tick labels you provided, which obviously don't look great (there's probably a few too many). Hope this helps and gives you a an area to explore.

[image: Axes tranformations]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'A': 0.9823, 'B': 0.9133, 'C': 0.9987, 'D': 0.7332, 'E': 0.1345, 'F': 0.9235}
yticks = np.array([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(16,4))

ax[0].bar(left=range(len(data)), height=np.array(data.values()), tick_label=data.keys())
ax[0].set_ylim(yticks[0], yticks[-1])
ax[0].set_title('Original scale')

epsilon = .1
ax[1].bar(left=range(len(data)), height=1/(1+epsilon-np.array(data.values())), tick_label=data.keys())
ax[1].set_yticks(1/(1+epsilon-yticks))
ax[1].set_yticklabels(yticks)
ax[1].set_ylim(1/(1+epsilon-yticks[0]),1/(1+epsilon-yticks[-1]))
ax[1].set_title(r'$\epsilon=0.5$')

epsilon = .05
ax[2].bar(left=range(len(data)), height=1/(1+epsilon-np.array(data.values())), tick_label=data.keys())
ax[2].set_yticks(1/(1+epsilon-yticks))
ax[2].set_yticklabels(yticks)
ax[2].set_ylim(1/(1+epsilon-yticks[0]),1/(1+epsilon-yticks[-1]))
ax[2].set_title(r'$\epsilon=0.1$')

epsilon = .01
ax[3].bar(left=range(len(data)), height=1/(1+epsilon-np.array(data.values())), tick_label=data.keys())
ax[3].set_yticks(1/(1+epsilon-yticks))
ax[3].set_yticklabels(yticks)
ax[3].set_ylim(1/(1+epsilon-yticks[0]),1/(1+epsilon-yticks[-1]))
ax[3].set_title(r'$\epsilon=0.05$')

fig.show()
```